# hibernate mapping 3 entities to one join table

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have 3 tables skill_checklist, skill_group, skill_master and a mapping table skill_checklist_group_master

The association is as

```
checklist <-- many to many --> Group 
Group <-- many to many --> skills
```

Can some one tell me how to manage this 3 table association in hibernate with annotations?

Below are my table structures

```
CREATE TABLE public.skill_checklist
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('skill_checklist_id_seq'::regclass),
  name character varying(256) NOT NULL,
  description character varying(500) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_SKILL_CHECKLIST_ID" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE public.skill_group
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('skill_group_id_seq'::regclass),
  name character varying(256) NOT NULL,
  description character varying(500) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_SKILL_GROUP_ID" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE public.skill_master
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('skill_master_id_seq'::regclass),
  name character varying(256) NOT NULL,
  description character varying(500) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_SKILL_MASTER_ID" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE public.skill_checklist_group_master
(
  checklist_id bigint NOT NULL,
  group_id bigint NOT NULL,
  skill_id bigint NOT NULL,
  group_order bigint NOT NULL,
  skill_order bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "FK_MAP_CHECKLIST_CHECKLIST_ID" FOREIGN KEY (checklist_id)
      REFERENCES public.skill_checklist (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT "FK_MAP_GROUP_GROUP_ID" FOREIGN KEY (group_id)
      REFERENCES public.skill_group (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT "FK_MAP_SKILL_SKILL_ID" FOREIGN KEY (skill_id)
      REFERENCES public.skill_master (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

I don't have experience with hibernate so coding examples will definately help me here. Using latest version of hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

With Hibernate you can define every datatable in a entity. Every entity has his own annotations for column.

Here is a example..

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "id")
   private int id;

   @Column(name = "first_name")
   private String firstName;

   @Column(name = "last_name")
   private String lastName;

   @Column(name = "salary")
   private int salary;  

   public Employee() {}
   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }
   public void setId( int id ) {
      this.id = id;
   }
   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }
   public void setFirstName( String first_name ) {
      this.firstName = first_name;
   }
   public String getLastName() {
      return lastName;
   }
   public void setLastName( String last_name ) {
      this.lastName = last_name;
   }
   public int getSalary() {
      return salary;
   }
   public void setSalary( int salary ) {
      this.salary = salary;
   }
}
```

How you can see every entity has his owns annotations and his owns methods for get and set data in his columns..

If you use eclipse or netbeans, they has his own plugins for convert datatables in entities automatically..

Comment: You have not helped at all...-1 for your answer. I am having problems with associations!

Comment: Ok.. but, do you have your entities created?? can you put your entities code??

Comment: If you need associate a entity with other. you need a JoinColumn annotation .. something like this